# Application Insight on premises without Internet Access

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-application-insights

I've to develop a WPF application in an intranet environment with no internet access for security reason. I was wondering if it's possible to collect data locally (on a server) then to FTP them or even better to have the application insight alternative installed on a Server.
Has anyone faced a similar situation and have been able to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do something like that yourself if you *really* needed to.  Instead of using the built in `InMemoryChannel` or `ServerChannel` classes to send telemetry, you'd create your own implementation to store them somewhere else. (or you could change the endpoint that the default channels point to to a web service inside the intranet.

you could then collect those files up and ftp them outside, and write another service to read those files and send the telemetry to app insights.  Though it seems less like a good idea given the intranet with no internet for security reasons.

Or, better yet, you could simply write internal service to parse and store all that telemetry and show it on that web service inside the intranet and use appinsights only as an sdk and schema, and don't send any of your data outside your intranet at all.

More likely: upvote adding AI to azure stack, (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/11683746-bring-application-insights-to-azure-stack) and then get an azure stack implementation inside your intranet?  then you get all the other goodies of Azure from Azure stack as well.

Comment: The problem of FTPing the collected files outside is that we have manually to ask the IT to perform the FTP...on the second point I would have to reimplement what app insight does...